# map overlay circle, missing drag event in google docs

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

i have a google map with a circle on it, as soon as i change the radius, i submit a form with new parameters,

this works very well with `editable:true` and `radius_changed`-event

because the radius_changed event fires when you finish your resize-move.

I want to do the same with the center_changed-event
but this one doesn´t fire when i "drop" the circle, it fires all the time the center changes,

i can´t find any drag-event of a circle in the docs,

the problem is that my form would instantly submit as soon as i move the circle a px.

here is my gmap3 code snippet

```
    circle:{
options:{
  center: destination,
  radius : distance,
  fillColor : "white",
  fillOpacity:0.3,
  strokeColor : "#c9311b",
  editable:true,
  draggable:true
},
events:{
  click: function(circle){
    circle.setOptions({
      fillColor : "white",
      fillOpacity:0.1,
      strokeColor : "#FF512F"  
    });
  },
  radius_changed: function(circle){
    var radius =circle.getRadius() ;
    var newradius = parseInt(radius) / 1000;
    alert(parseInt(newradius,10));
    $('#seldistance').val(parseInt(newradius,10));
    $('.sucheen').submit();

  },
  center_changed: function(circle){   //
    var center = circle.getCenter();  // Here´s the center change event,
    console.log(center);              //it really spams the console when you drag
  }                                   //
},
callback: function(circle){
    if(distance != '0'){
        if ( distance < '1000'){
            $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(15);
            console.log('radius ='+distance);
        }
        else if ( distance < '5000'){
            $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(13);
            console.log('radius ='+distance);
        }
        else if ( distance < '10000'){
            $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(12);
            console.log('radius ='+distance);
        }
        else if ( distance < '20000'){
            $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(11);
            console.log('radius ='+distance);
        }
        else if ( distance < '35000'){
            $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(10);
            console.log('radius ='+distance);
        }
        else{
        $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(10);   
        }
    }
    else {
    //Clear circle if no radius is set
    $(this).gmap3({
      clear: {
        name:["circle"],
        last: true
      }
    });
    $(this).gmap3('get').setZoom(12);
    }
}
},//close circle
```

anyone has an idea how to trigger the dragend event ?=

ok i realized that the function i want comes with editable:true
but only when i use the little center point to drag, i would love to drag the whole circle anywhere
thanks in advance for ***any*** hint

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my sollution is this. I know if mouse is down - in that case circle center is not already set. When mouse is up, center is set. I need to use timeout because center_change event is faster that mouseup event.

For some reason the center_changed event is fired twice at the end. If that bothers you, it's possible to use Ben Alman's [Throttle / Debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

```
var mousedown;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    mousedown = true;
});
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    mousedown = false;
});

gmaps.event.addListener(this.circle, 'center_changed', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!mousedown) {
            console.log('center changed');
        }
    }, 10);
}
```